# Breeze EF SaveChanges() on a DTO

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, dto

I've been struggling with Breeze to SaveChanges to a projection and admit I new to both EF and breeze. There were some similar questions earlier when I was trying to use WCF, but now I have abandoned WCF and added EF directly to my solution.

In my controller I return the DTO for the metadata to breeze along with the DTO and it binds perfectly.

After altering the data on the client my Breese Controllers [HttpPost] SaveChanges(save Bundle) is called and map contains the DTO and the changes.

How Do I persist the Changes? If I re-read the DTO projection for breeze to update then EF cant save a projection because it's not "tracked", if I read the Full entity, then Breeze error with "Sequence contains no matching element" because its looking for the DTO? Am I suppose to use AutoMapper?

Controller:

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{

   readonly EFContextProvider<ManiDbContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<ManiDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return  _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ConsigneDTO> Consignee(string refname)
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.consigneDTO(refname);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        ManiDbContextProvider _mcontextProvider = new ManiDbContextProvider();
        return  _mcontextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

ManiDbContext (the main DBContext is CifContext which is Database First/EF Reverse Engineer)

```
 public class ManiDbContext  : DbContext 
 {
    public CifContext CifDbContext = new CifContext();


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>(); 
        Database.SetInitializer<ManiDbContext>(null);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConsigneDTOMap());
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        CifDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return 1;
    }

    public IQueryable<ConsigneDTO> consigneDTO(string refname)
    {
        IQueryable<ConsigneDTO> q = this.CifDbContext.Consignes
         .Where(x => x.Refname == refname)
         .Select(f => new ConsigneDTO {Refname = f.Refname, Consignee = f.Consignee, Address1 = f.Address1, Address2 = f.Address2, Address3 = f.Address3});

        return q;
    }
```

ManiDbContextProvider

```
    public class ManiDbContextProvider : EFContextProvider<CifContext>
//  public class ManiDbContextProvider : EFContextProvider<ManiDbContext>
  {
    public ManiDbContextProvider() : base() { }

    protected override void OpenDbConnection()
    {// do nothing
    }

    protected override void CloseDbConnection()
    { // do nothing 
    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        var entity = entityInfo.Entity;

        if (entity is ConsigneDTO)
        {
            return BeforeSaveConsignee(entity as ConsigneDTO, entityInfo);
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot save entity of unknown type");
    }

     private bool BeforeSaveConsignee(ConsigneDTO c, EntityInfo info)
    {

        var consdata = this.Context.CifDbContext.Consignes 
             .Where(x => x.Refname == c.Refname)
             .FirstOrDefault();   // ENTITY 

      //  var consdata = this.Context.consigneDTO(c.Refname); // DTO 

       return (null != consdata) || throwCannotFindConsignee();
    }
```

CifContext   (Full Columns - First/EF Reverse Engineer/ Consigne class contains Keys)

```
  public partial class CifContext : DbContext
  {
    static CifContext()
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<CifContext>(null);
    }

    public CifContext()
        : base("Name=CifContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Consigne> Consignes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();   // Use singular table names
        Database.SetInitializer<CifContext>(null);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ConsigneMap());
     }
```

Regardless if I Read the Entity or the DTO - I'm Clueless on how breeze updates EF

Any Help greatly appreciated :)

Regards,
Mike

Comment: It sounds like this is a perfect case scenario for a custom save interception on the controller.

Comment: @PWKad Appreciate the help, Thank you! I was thinking that way too, shame breese would have the ability to roll it all back if I could just rename the DTO to the entity. Do you recommend AutoMapper? Any good breese samples that come to mind?